# AMPscript for adding the Order Number to an email subject

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

I am trying to add the order number to an email subject and I don't know-how. Plus I am really new to the AMPscript world.

I want my email subject to be like: ''Your #OrderID is on the go''

for the moment I went here and choose the Data Extension and then the field that I wanted to be mapped

[image: AMPscript in subjectline]

Can you please advise?

Comment: And did it work?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend adding an AMPscript block at beginning of your email body and setting the subject there:

```ampscript
%%[

var @subject
var @idCommanda
set @idCommanda = AttributeValue("idCommanda") /* check if this send context attribute has a value */

if not empty(@idCommanda) then
  set @subject = concat("Comanda ta #", @idCommanda, " fost expidiata")
else
  set @subject = concat("Comanda ta fost expidiata")
endif

]%%
```

Then in the Subject field:

```
%%=v(@subject)=%%
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much.